# Sort a HashMap, define the limit and convert to ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a HashMap like this:

```
public final Map<String, MyClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And now I need to sort this hashmap, define the limt and convert to ArrayList. I did the code bellow:

```
List<MyClass> collect = myMap.values().stream().sorted((m1, m2) -> Double.compare(m2.getSomething(), m1.getSomething())).limit(amount).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem is that this code is not performance and efficient. myMap is huge, so the code is taking too much time to finish.
Any idea how to deal with scenario?

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: When I run this code takes 2 hours to complete. If I remove the sorted function the code takes 23 seconds.
The problem is that I need the sorted function

Comment: How is `amount` related to the size of the map? Like, is it a half of that size or 10% or just a few items? My point is, if `amount` is low, you don't need to sort the rest of the map.

Answer (score 2):

If your `Map` is really as big as you say it is, there's potential that you can benefit from using a parallel stream instead of a sequential one.  Also, assuming that `MyClass#getSomething` returns a `double`, you can use `Comparator#comparingDouble`:

```
List<MyClass> collect;

collect = myMap.values()
               .parallelStream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(MyClass::getSomething).reversed())
               .limit(amount)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I split the declaration and initialization into two lines to make it take up slightly less space.

Comment: Another solution could be create the map in an orderly way to avoid doing the sort after?

Comment: I’m not sure if built-in classes (such as `TreeMap`) allow you to build a `Map` while sorting it by value, you’ll still have to get the `n`th element somehow though.

Comment: This code change is not yet performing as much as is needed. By changing the hashmap to a simple array, would it be more advantageous?